# How do I update xref-backend-functions?

Tags: variables, xref

I'm not sure what kind of variable `xref-backend-functions` and how to update it.

After I open a .c file, I do `M-:` and do

```
(add-hook 'xref-backend-functions #'gxref-xref-backend)
```

and it shows me

```
(gxref-xref-backend etags--xref-backend)
```

So it looks updated, but then if I do `M-:` and type

```
xref-backend-functions
```

emacs shows me

```
(eglot-xref-backend t)
```

And so `xref-backend-functions` is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hook variable. A hook variable has a global part, and the buffer-local part(s), the latter can be different between many modes.

In your example `(eglot-xref-backend t)` is a buffer-local value (with the special element `t` meaning to run the global value's functions as well), and `(gxref-xref-backend etags--xref-backend)` is the global value (which you updated with `add-hook`).

The usual way to update the buffer-local value is to pass the LOCAL=t argument to `add-hook` because the local values usually takes precedence over the global one.

The code which would call `add-hook` usually resides in some minor mode. But if you are writing your personal customization, you could put it in a function which is in turn added to some major mode hook. To `c-mode-hook`, for instance.

As a result the local value in `c-mode` buffers will be altered.